# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta para mostrar la cantidad de registros en cada zona?

Tags: laravel

Quiero mostrar un directorio de servicios por provincias y ciudades, y dentro de cada una mostrar la cantidad de registro encontrados en cada una.

Ejemplo:

**Buenos Aires (15)**

Capital Federal (10) - La Plata (5)

**Córdoba (10)**

Villa Carlos Paz (5) - Códoba (5)

Tengo una base de datos, y en ella unas tablas: Provincia y Ciudad ... en ellas guardo dicha información, a esto le defino registros. Dicha información la quiero mostrar como lo describí antes, que me muestre mientras allá registros, el nombre de la provincia la cantidad de registros que tiene para mostrarla entre paréntesis, ejemplo: Buenos Aires (15)... igualmente con las ciudades. Espero me haya explicado mejor.

**No tengo idea de como hacer la consulta**

Comment: Formula mejor tu pregunta amigo no es suficiente información para ayudarte

Comment: Hola Diego, tengo una base de datos, y en ella unas tablas: Provincia y Ciudad ... en ellas guardo dicha información, a esto le defino registros. Dicha información la quiero mostrar como lo describí en la pregunta, que me muestre mientras allá registros, el nombre de la provincia y la cantidad de registros que tiene, para mostrarla entre paréntesis, ejemplo: Buenos Aires (15)... igualmente con las ciudades. Espero me haya explicado mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno puedes hacerlo de 2 modos, la comun realizar una consulta sql con INNER JOIN, GROUBY, ETC como la necesites Pruebala en tu editor de sql.

Luego ejecutala en `DB::select($query)` esto te regresa un array de objetos con los datos de la consulta.

Otra forma es usando las realaciones en laravel puedes buscar mas de esto en la documentación del framework. Por o que describes ha de ser una relacion uno a muchos osea hasMany.

```
$provincias = Provincias::has('registros')->with('registros')->get()

foreach ($provincias as $provincia) {
   echo $provincia->name." (".$provincia->registros->count().")<br>";
}
```

Comment: Espero te sirva revisa la documentación de laravel si no entiendes algunas cosas.

Comment: No termina de quedar claro el por que hay un `registro` en el `has` y luego `registros` en el `with`

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a intentar

Comment: bueno fue mi error es "registros" y asi deberia llamarse la relación definida en el modelo provincias.

Comment: A lo que iba con mi pregunta es ¿Lo or que has y with al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Bueno pasa que con has haces el filtro para que solo traiga las provincias que tengas registros es decir omitas las que no tiene registros. En uno de los comentarion mencionaron  --"muestre mientras allá registros"